# Adding Json Image to ListTile

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a simple json parser and listing the news and their categories

now I am trying to do some optimisations on ListTile because I would like to use the news Images bigger and put the news title under but ListTile provide only trailing which it is unusable for me. But I can't add any styling in whole code (new child, Row, etc gives error.) Is it possible to do that in this structure or should I make a customListTile on another page and link the current mechanism to new page?

any help would be really nice

```
body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(
          10.0,
        ),
        child: FutureBuilder<Articles>(
          future: _futureArticles,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Articles> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              final articles = snapshot.data?.data;

              return ListView.builder(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(
                  10.0,
                ),
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: articles!.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Card(
                    elevation: 4.0,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    ),
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                        'Title: ${articles[index].title}',
                      ),
                      subtitle:
                          Text('Category: ${articles[index].category?.name}'),
                      trailing: Image.network(articles[index].imageUrl!),
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => NewsViewDetail(
                              id: articles[index].id!,
                            ),
                            fullscreenDialog: true,
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return NewsError(
                errorMessage: '${snapshot.hasError}',
              );
            } else {
              return const NewsLoading(
                text: 'Loading...',
              );
            }
          },
        ),
        
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your imagine not display in trailing section? Are you share your API url?

Comment: no it is displaying but trailer function of ListTile is not a good solution because I would like to display the images bigger and not at right

Comment: You want to display it on left and bigger? Just like this image https://images.app.goo.gl/UqWTzdeNBrvG857DA

Comment: no like this https://monosnap.com/file/qVaqxwruqWHEDrxqUdD2xlQczvS8hh

Answer (score 0):

Try below answer hope its help to you ,use **GridView.builder()** instead of **ListView.builder()**

```
Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
  child: GridView.builder(
    itemCount: 5,//use your length here(articles!.length)
    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    shrinkWrap: true,
    gridDelegate:
      SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 1),
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey.shade200),
       ),
       margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
       padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
       child: Column(
         crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
         children: [
           Expanded(
             child: Image.network(
               'your network image here',
               fit: BoxFit.fill,
             ),
           ),
           SizedBox(
            height: 15,
           ),
           Text(
             'Your headline here',
             style: TextStyle(
               fontSize: 15,
               fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
             ),
           ),
         
         ],
       ),
     );
   },
  ),
);
```

your screen look like -> [image]